Health check errors on deployment firebase functions v1
I currently have a couple v1 onRequest firebase functions.  When I deploy these functions, it triggers a large amount of status code 500 healthcheck logs to fire off that look something like this:

The request was aborted because there was no available instance. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability

My V1 onRequest functions are fairly simple and run fine in production (no errors, etc.). I don't really get why there is no available instance, could this be due to a cold start issue? Do I need to set the minInstance to 1 or something along those lines?
It seems to happen for each v1 onRequest function upon deployment.  The odd thing is it doesn't happen on every deployment, so it kinda seems random to me.  Is there anything I can do to ensure these healthcheck pings don't create errors on my end.

all of the suggested answers are bs and unhelpful read all of them before... but alright
